# Three questions about editbox?

Tags: windows, winapi, controls, editcontrol

I have three questions about editbox control in WINAPI (i can't find information on msdn about this)
1. How to disable moving typeing cursor with mouse, arrows, backspace in editbox ? I want to make typing like in command line in dos, but with out backspace.

2. Can I write some piece of text with red color, and another with blue ?
3. How to write to editbox control from another thread ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make it read-only (`ES_READONLY`) & manually intercept keystrokes and append only those you want to.
2. No, you would need to use a `RICHEDIT` class for that and use RTF. (You could owner draw a normal EDIT window but that would not be much fun)
3. `SendMessage` with `WM_SETTEXT` (Or `EM_SETTEXTEX` / `EM_REPLACESEL` if you use a `RICHEDIT`)

Why not use a Console?

Comment: It must be in window :/
To answer 1. - Are there any other option instead of ES_READONLY and intercept keystrokes ? I asking beacouse in my language there is a lot of combinations on keyboard to make variuos characters.

Comment: You can intercept WM_CHAR & examine its value, discarding if appropriate.

Comment: Thx.
Can I disable mouse selection in richedit ?
I append char with this code:
   SendMessage(richEdit, EM_SETSEL, - 1, 0);
   SendMessage(richEdit,EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, (LPARAM)&cf);
   SendMessage(richEdit, EM_REPLACESEL, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)(LPSTR)msg); 

But when I click on richedit with mouse this code doesn't work :/

Comment: You could discard mouse messages, WM_LBUTTONDOWN et al.